# Android Studio cannot open layout xml

Tags: xml, android-studio, layout

suddenly my android studio damaged and it cannot to open a XML of layout.
When I double click on layout xml it doesn't show in code editor also when I drag and drop xml file from project path android studio cannot to show it
please help me 
thanks!

[image]

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: Have you cleaned or rebuild the project?

Comment: yeah, over and over...

Comment: Had the same issue. Restart nope. Clean nope. build nope. rebuild nope. run on emulator then suddenly it all works like nothing was wrong?? as in runs fine on emulator and then my XML's start opening again...

Answer (score 4):

Go to `plugins -> Android support` and disable this. Restart Android studio and enable the plugin again.
Worked for me.

Comment: can't see plugis in settings

Answer (score 1):

Restart your Android Studio, if not working, Restart your PC.

Comment: I remove completely android studio and reinstall it , but ploblem not solved!

Comment: it happen in any XML file?

Comment: No it just happend for layouts. there is no any problem for other folders like anim , menu ,...

Comment: if you create new Layout?

Comment: When I want to create an new xml layout it give an error: "Must not pass null editor in [null,Editor: path_off_xml_in_HDD]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Be sure that your XML is valid (with another text editor), then clean project and rebuild it. Wait for the new project indexing process finish, and it should work.

If not, try by restart AS with invalidate cache.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue because I enabled Proguard in my debug build. After disabling that, I am able to open layout files in my project. 
Do the below in your app gradle file.

```
debug 
{
    minifyEnabled false
}
```

Hope it would help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Refresh your Gradle project.

I tried to invalidate and restart, disable Android Support plugin, rebuild project and still got the issue.
I tried Refreshing Gradle project and problem solved.

[image: Refresh all Gradle project action icon]

Answer (score 0):

Please check your gradle-wrapper.properties file and make sure proper url is given

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-milestone-1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Click File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate caches And Restart.

Answer (score 0):

Ok It was very stupid, and I had not coded in Android Studio for a while, but:

The reason while I could not open the .xml file (loading non stop) was that I was using the image view (two little triangles that look like mountains) instead of the code view (4 dashes), switch in the top right corner above "Loading...". I hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

N.B: It's not a permanent solution. But a quick hack.

For those, whose nothing is working. right-click on the file. click show in explorer. then drag-drop the file to android studio.

Answer (score -1):

It could be a keymap conflict. I set the double click for a plugin, and that was the cause.